# What causes "Authentication is needed to run '/bin/dd' as the super user" prompt when modifying files created via docker shell?

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu

[image]

I am running a website (built with Laravel) in a Docker container. From within the docker bash shell, I ran some artisan commands (e.g. php artisan make:migration create_users_table). I am guessing the files created by these commands are owned by some Docker user group.

When I try to modify and then save these files (in my IDE, probably as a different user from the Docker user), I get the authentication prompt above. Why is this happening, and what could /bin/dd have to do with this? (I read that dd is a Unix command line utility for converting/copying files, which could have something to do with this).

Comment: I've never heard of such a situation. Especially as all commands should run within the running containers, it looks pretty strange to me that such a dialog should be triggered by this

Comment: At the moment, I'm just using chown to manually change ownership of files from root to my user, i.e. sudo chown yourusernamehere path/to/file. This solves the issue for a given file, but it still has to be done for each new file created by the docker user.

Comment: How is chowning files related to the given dialog? Could you at least share some details?

Comment: "I am guessing the files created by these commands are owned by some Docker user group." Files created from within the docker container are created by the user 'root'. I am chowning files to change the ownership to my user. I am new to Unix shell, and I am guessing this is a simple fix, like adding my user and (maybe) root or docker to the same usergroup. However, I've tried adding myself to the docker user group, which didn't fix the problem. I added the previous comment to give a quick-fix to anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this, and for me it was my editor (Atom).

https://github.com/atom/fs-admin/blob/3076674c475b4620390f5e80c9354e1d9aedb3df/README.md#packaging-linux-only

I imagine other editors may do something similar.

You could figure it out by running top in tree mode (press capital `V` while running top), then attempting to save a file that was created in your docker container.